# Sql: choose all baskets containing a set of particular items

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-division

Eddy has baskets with items. Each item can belong to arbitrary number of baskets or can belong to none of them.

Sql schema to represent it is as following:

```
tbl_basket
- basketId

tbl_item
- itemId

tbl_basket_item
- pkId
- basketId
- itemId
```

**Question:** how to select all baskets containing a particular set of items?

**UPDATE.** Baskets with **all** the items are needed. Otherwise it would have been easy task to solve.

**UPDATE B.** Have implemented following solution, including SQL generation in PHP:

```
SELECT basketId
FROM   tbl_basket
JOIN   (SELECT basketId FROM tbl_basket_item WHERE itemId = 1  ) AS t0 USING(basketId)
JOIN   (SELECT basketId FROM tbl_basket_item WHERE itemId = 15 ) AS t1 USING(basketId)
JOIN   (SELECT basketId FROM tbl_basket_item WHERE itemId = 488) AS t2 USING(basketId)
```

where number of *JOINs* equals to number of items.

That works good unless some of the items are included in almost every basket. Then performance drops dramatically.

**UPDATE B+.** To resolve performance issues heuristic is applied. First you select frequency of each item. If it exceeds some threshold, you don't include it in *JOINs* and either:

- apply post-filtering in PHP
- or just don't apply filter by particular itemId, giving a user approximate results in a resonable amount of time

**UPDATE B++.** Seems that current problem have no nice solution in MySQL. This point raises one question and one solution:

- *(question)* Does PostgreSQL have some advanced indexing techniques which allows to solve this problem without doing a full scan?
- *(solution)* Seems that it could be solved nicely in *Redis* using sets and *SINTER* command to get an intersection.

Comment: How about `SELECT (DISTINCT if needed) tb.* FROM tbl_basket_item tbi JOIN tbl_basket tb ON tbi.basketId=tb.basketId JOIN tbl_item ti ON tbi.itemID = ti.itemId WHERE tbi.itemId IN (1,2,3, ...)`?

Comment: Using IN would also return baskets that only contain a part of the needed items.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I think this is more of a "how would you do this in a DBMS of you choice" kind of question :)

Comment: School work? If so, please inform us.

Comment: @jarlh Not at all) Just added some story behind not to bore SO people with business stuff.

Comment: Looks like a relational division problem. Standard solution is the double NOT EXISTS().

Comment: @joop Would you be so kind to explain in more detail?

Comment: Has been answered more than once. Please look at the other answers. [ I added the tag, so they should show up in the `related` section to the right -->> ] For instance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32228433/postgres-exclusive-tag-search

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is to create a temporary table with the set of needed items (procedure that takes the item ids as parameters or something along those lines) and then left join it with all of the above tables joined together.

If for a given basketid you have NO nulls on the right side of the left join, the basket contains all the needed items.

Comment: PS - if you want the basket to contain ONLY those items, do a full join and make sure there are no nulls on either side for a given basketid

Comment: That counts as a solution for sure. Just hoped to find something simpler and more like a ready-recipe for the situation looks like a generic task to me.

Comment: Only other solution i can think of implies string concatenation - the performance drop would probably be too high.

Answer (score 1):

```
-- the table definitions
CREATE TABLE basket ( basketid INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE item ( itemid INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE basket_item
        ( basketid INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES basket (basketid)
        , itemid INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES item (itemid)
        , PRIMARY KEY (basketid, itemid)
        );

-- the query
SELECT * FROM basket b
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM item i
        WHERE i.itemid IN (1,15,488)
        AND NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT * FROM basket_item bi
                WHERE bi.basketid = b.basketid
                AND bi.itemid = i.itemid
                )
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to provide the list of items, then edit id1, id2, etc. in below query:

```
select distinct t.basketId
from tbl_basket_item as t
where t.itemID in (id1, id2)
```

will give all baskets containing a set of items. No need to join any other tables as your requirements don't need them.

Comment: Using IN would also return baskets that only contain a part of the needed items. I don't think that's what the OP asked for.

Comment: There is no separate schema linking items with baskets, which your interpretation of the question entails. I'm sure OP would have shown that. In any case, I can revise if that's what OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to use `HAVING` clause.

```
SELECT basketId
FROM   tbl_basket
WHERE itemId IN (1,15,488)
HAVING Count(DISTINCT itemId) = 3 --DISTINCT in case we have duplicate items in a basket
GROUP BY basketId
```

Comment: I'll try that, but not sure it performs well for heavy tables.

Comment: @DenisKulagin That would depend on your data but certainly it should behave better then the query in your question. Well, at least in most cases.