# PostgreSQL: intersect index scans on the same index

Tags: sql, postgresql, bitmap-index

Trying to solve this problem: [Sql: choose all baskets containing a set of particular items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32391831/sql-choose-all-baskets-containing-a-set-of-particular-items)

In other words there is a table:

```
tbl_basket_item
--    
basketId itemId

1 2
1 3
1 4
2 3
2 4
3 2
3 4
```

*itemId* is indexed.

If I perform a scan on *itemId=2*, I'll get:

```
SELECT basketId FROM tbl_basket_item WHERE itemId = 2

1
3
```

If I perform a scan on *itemId=4*, I'll get:

```
SELECT basketId FROM tbl_basket_item WHERE itemId = 4

1
2
3
```

Can I now intersect those two scans to get:

```
SELECT basketId FROM tbl_basket WHERE
  basketId IN (SELECT basketId FROM tbl_basket_item WHERE itemId = 2) AND
  basketId IN (SELECT basketId FROM tbl_basket_item WHERE itemId = 4)

1
3
```

using some PostgeSQL advanced indexing techs, like *bitmap indices*?

Comment: What exactly is your question? Are you looking for the `interesct` operator? I also don't see how a specific index _type_ is relevant for your question. Do you have performance problems with that statement? If yes then please read this: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions

Comment: The double NOT EXISTS() query generates an index scan for the inner query on the junction table (even for this very small rowcount=7)

Comment: @joop I'll give it a try!

Comment: What is the exact problem here? If you want to use postgres you could change the data structure and use arrays to store items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You effectively get an "intersect index scan" (whatever that *effectively* is) by doing a standard `INTERSECT` on your `SELECT`:

```
SELECT basketId FROM tbl_basket_item WHERE itemId = 2
INTERSECT
SELECT basketId FROM tbl_basket_item WHERE itemId = 4;
```

Comment: That's what I've been looking for! What's about performance? (Haven't found any notes about that on the official page).